# Patching UEFI Pei module problems with addresses

Tags: patch, bios, uefi

I want to patch some UEFI PEI module of an older BIOS and I encountered some problem.
hex edit and insert one function from other BIOS
Now I need to fix some offsets.
These addresses are from .data section, and are some predefined values.
I fixed most of them except these
This are from file disassembled with IDA
in original code                        hex bytes

```
cmp     byte_FFFAC358, 0FFh         80 3D 58 C3 FA FF FF
mov     ecx, offset byte_FFFAC358   B9 58 C3 FA FF
mov     cl, byte_FFFAC359[eax]      8A  88 59 C3 FA FF
mov     al, byte_FFFAC35A[eax]      8A 80 5A C3 FA FF
lea     ecx, byte_FFFAC358[eax]     8D 88 58 C3 FA FF
```

but in my BIOS module that data is located at different address.
0xFFFAC358 is at 0xFFFB60B4
0xFFFAC359 is at 0xFFFB60B5
0xFFFAC35A is at 0xFFFB60B6

I try to fix this and resulting code is

```
cmp    byte ptr ds:unk_FFFB63B4, 0FFh       80 3D B4 60 FB FF FF
mov    ecx, offset byte_FFFB60B4            B9 B4 60 FB FF
mov    cl, ds:byte_FFFB60B5[eax]            8A 88 B5 60 FB FF
mov    al, ds:byte_FFFB60B6[eax]            8A 80 B6 60 FB FF
lea    ecx, byte_FFFB60B4[eax]              8D 88 B4 60 FB FF
```

Second and fifth lines seems Ok
Third and fourth may be also OK, im not 100% sure
But for the firt line there is an offset of 0x300 from what must be.

I'm a newbiee so pleas enlight me what I do wrong.

Checked on dogbolt org
For that part of code 80 3D B4 60 FB FF FF

```
Hex-Rays    if ( unk_FFFB63B4 != 0xFF )
Ghidra      if (DAT_fffb60b4 != -1)
BinaryNinja char* ecx_1 = &data_fffb60b4
```

Comment: In the original code, the first, second, and fifth lines have the same  address, and it is one less than the address in the third line. In the modified code, the same is true, so the code is fine. Why do you think it should be FFFB63B4?

Comment: Because that show IDA.Checked online on few disassembler and all show right value for 80 3D B4 60 FB FF FF cmp    byte_FFFB60B4, 0FFh But in IDA shows as cmp    byte ptr ds:unk_FFFB63B4, 0FFh

Comment: Edited first message.
It may be IDA related problem